# Change State of Windows Update- Local Group Policy Editor without UI?

Tags: script, automation, powershell-2.0, gpedit

In windows server 2012,for this manual step how can i do from script,

```
start>run>gpedit.msc>administrative Components>Windows>Windows update
```

In that

1) Do not Display " **Install updates and Shutdown**" by default it is " **Not Configured**" want to change it to enabled

2) Always automatically restart at scheduled, state should be enabled and, want to change work minutes as 50 minutes

3)Configure automatic updates, as "Enabled" and want to pass value to **"configure automatic updates"**

How can i Do it from command line or any script like power shell, anything, because i want to automatically if i run the script?